# LJ Dynamic Fields unable to output title

Tags: templating

I’m using the [LJ Dynamic Fields](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields) plugin and have a dynamic multi select setup for the client to select predefined tags, which is working all fine in the cms using the following code.

```
{% for tags in craft.tags.group('default').limit(null).order('title') %}
{ "value":"{{ tags.id }}" , "label":"{{ tags | raw | capitalize }}"
}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, in my template I can only seem to output the id, but I want the tag title. I’m using the following code in my template:

```
{% for tags in entry.tagsMultiSelect %}
<a href="">{{ tags }}</a>
{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone tell me where I’m going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in your `tagsMultiSelect` are the tag ids, not the tags.
So, what you need to do in your template is convert that id to a tag:

```
{% for tagId in entry.tagsMultiSelect %}
  {# get the tag with that id #}
  {% set tag = craft.tags.id(tagId).first %}

  <a href="">{{ tag.title ?? 'no such tag' }}</a>
  {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

If what you want is a predefined set of tags, you might also consider changing that tag group into a category - that would let you use a regular category field for your `tagsMultiSelect`.